# Calculating Cohen's d

Tags: pre-post-comparison, cohens-d

I have two groups (experimental and control) and a measure (an estimate of confidence) measured at baseline and at post-intervention. I have ran a multiple regression and found that the intervention condition (experimental or control) has a significant effect on baseline to post-intervention confidence. Based on some other StackExchange posts, I calculated Cohen's f-squared as a measure of effect size. However, I also need to calculate the Cohen's d because it is the more commonly reported measure of effect size. To calculate Cohen's d, do I compare `baseline of experimental` vs. `post_intervention of experimental` OR `(baseline-post_intervention) of experimental` vs. `(baseline-post_intervention) of control`? I realize the question indicates a lack of basic understanding, but I could really use some help.

Comment: You could calculate Cohen's *d* for whichever pairs of groups you want.  However, there's some discussion about how to calculate Cohen's *d* for groups from a larger regression model, as the standard error from the analysis isn't simply the standard deviation from any of the groups.

Comment: Can you please share the literature?

Comment: I don't have any specific recommendations for publications on this, but you might start with this discussion: [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603792/whats-the-appropriate-effect-size-estimate-and-power-analysis-for-post-hoc-re](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603792/whats-the-appropriate-effect-size-estimate-and-power-analysis-for-post-hoc-re).  ...  As mentioned there, if you are using R, and a general linear model, the `eff_size()` function in the *emmeans*  package calculates a Cohen's *d* -like effect sizes from the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!